# What does the "B" in the Web Applications beta logo stand for?

Tags: discussion, area-51, beta-sites, logo, site-specific

Is it "B" as in "Beta"?

(Yes, I get know that it's not the permanent logo - I'm just curious why it was chosen as the temp one.)

I didn't commit, so if this is explained somewhere on the WebApps Meta, etc., be patient with me.

The logo in question: [image: Some Logo...Beta. But really, wasn't it obvious?]

Comment: What logo? The screenshot on the blog shows the word "Beta", not a "B".

Comment: The image is broken, but I'm guessing this question would be obsolete even if it were fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Jeff's answer to the same question on meta.webapps.stackexchange.com:

> Beta, but this is subject to change.

Answer (score 2):

It means *Beta*